# How to remove all elements that satisfy a criteria in C# collection?

Tags: c#

I have a string array:

```
string[] names;
```

I want to remove all names that has length less than `k`. How can I do that? Do I have to convert it back to `List<string>` ?

Thanks, 
Chan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a `string[]` can't change it size you can't remove elements from it. So you need to create a new, smaller array with `names.Where(s=>!(s.Length<k)).ToArray()`.

On `List<string>` you can remove elements inplace with the `RemoveAll(s=>s.Length<k)` function.

Comment: You need to use a different parameter name for the lambda expression, but otherwise this is right.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Thanks. I got it now.

Comment: add this , `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yep, removed my comment after I realized I forgot the "using", but everyone was too fast.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ would be like this

```
List<String> list1 = new List<string>();
List<String> list2 = list1.Except(list1.Where(c => c.Length < 10)).ToList();
```

Comment: This removes duplicates too since `Except` only returns distinct elements. And the OP has an array, not a list. And personally I don't like the unnecessary use of `Except` instead of simply negating the predicate.